# How can I create ONE single function that will be called by an event listener instead of function for each different button?

Tags: javascript, function, events, addeventlistener, delegation

```
 function buttonOne() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage =
    'url(imgs/advbackground1.jpg)';
}

function buttonTwo() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage =
    'url(imgs/advbackground2.jpg)';
}


 
function buttonThree() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage =
    'url(imgs/advbackground3.jpg)';
}

function buttonFour() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage =
    'url(imgs/advbackground4.jpg)';
}
```

//each button changes the background to something new. I struggling to find an effective way of creating one single function to be able pass to an event listener when each button is clicked

Comment: Please add a tag showing which language this is.

Comment: sorry haha thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that has a parameter (or argument).

```
function anybutton(whichButton)
{
 document.body.style.backgroundImage = 
          'url(imgs/advbackground' + whichButton + '.jpg)';
}
```

Then on button #1: "onclick=anybutton(1);" and similarly for the others
If the required action is more complex, you can use "if" statements on whichButton, or write whatever code is required.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the buttons in a querySelectorAll array, and then you can either use a switch statement based on the event.id to change background image or whatever you're doing.. or you could map.set your images as values with keys that match the ids of your buttons, and map.get the value that matches your id.

```
const rangeOfButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".button-class")
let targetButton = "" //to give you higher scope.
for(i=0;i<rangeOfButtons.length;i++){
  rangeOfButtons[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){
    targetButton = e.target.id
   })
}
```